# How can we apply for a UK EEA family permit?

Tags: united-kingdom

My wife and I live in Poland; she is a Polish citizen and I have a Polish residence card. We want to apply for an EEA Family Permit to move to the UK. Can we apply online for the EEA family permit?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can apply for an EEA family permit.

To apply for an EEA family permit, you should start at https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/overview.  You should read all of the pages except for those on *Surinder Singh* and *derivative rights of residence*, which do not apply to you.  (Surinder Singh applies to British citizens and their non-EU family members, and derivative rights apply to certain relationships other than marriage.)

One of the pages includes the link for the application system (https://www.gov.uk/apply-uk-visa).